# Problema para validar un registro ya insertado en mi BD con Ajax Laravel 5.2

Tags: ajax

Tengo un formulario y en el cual ingreso 1 Email el cual en mi BD puse el campo como Unique el problema que me surge es al momento de volver a cargar un registro con el mismo Email me bota el error de SQL de que el campo ya esta registrado, pero me gustaría poder validar ates ese campo con Ajax para que no me bote ese error y la verdad soy nuevo con esto de Ajax y Laravel 5.2

```
    <form method="POST" action="correcto" name="formulario">
    <label>Correo electrónico</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
    <button class"btn" type="submit" value="enviar"></button>
    </form>
```

Esta es mi ruta

```
Route::post('correcto', 'RegistroController@recibir');
```

Este es mi controlador donde ingreso el registro a mi BD

```
public function recibir (Request $request){
$email = $request->input('email');
$guardado = new Registros;
$guardado->email = $email;
}
```

He investigado un poco y estoy viendo mas o menos la estructura que se debe de formar la petición con Ajax pero no se bien como estructurarlo todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer la validación en el mismo request que estas enviando a través del validador que trae Laravel, para ello basta agregarle esto al código que tienes en tu controlador:

```
 //Creamos las reglas de validación
   $rules = [
        'email'      => 'unique'
   ];
  // Ejecutamos el validador, en caso de que falle devolvemos la respuesta
   $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
   if ($validator->fails())
       return \Response::json([
           'error'  => $validator->errors()->all()
       ],422);
   }
```

Quedando tu código de esta manera:

```
public function recibir(Request $request){
  $rules = [
            'email'      => 'unique'
         ];
  $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
       if ($validator->fails())
           return \Response::json([
               'error'  => $validator->errors()->all()
           ],422);
       }
  $email = $request->input('email');
  $guardado = new Registros;
  $guardado->email = $email;
}
```

Ahora si lo que quieres es estrictamente hacer una solicitud Ajax para validar el email antes de enviar todo el formulario, basta con ignorar todo lo anterior, tomar el email (puedes usar JQuery para ello) y enviarlo al servidor para hacer la respectiva validación. Aquí pongo un ejemplo de una estructura Ajax usando JQuery que puedes utilizar para enviarlo a tu servidor Laravel:

```
var email = $('#email').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'tu/url/' + email,
    type: "GET", //Basta realizar una petición GET para hacer una consulta de validación
    success: function(response){
      //Tu código tras verificar que esté todo OK (Response 200)
    },
    error: function(response){
      //Tu código en caso de que haya error (por email repetido, etc)
      //IMPORTANTE: Devolver un código de respuesta diferente 
      // de 200 para que entre en esta función.
    }
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado con tu problema. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 0):

hola me ha servido mucho lo que me propuso, me base más en la segunda opción 
solo que ahora cambie un poco mi url con la cual trato de validar si existe ese correo en la BD o no y al momento de ejecutarlo siempre me marca que es correcto cuando debería de identificar que el correo ya existe

dejo el código

este es mi script

```
<script>
       function validarCorreo(){
         var email = $('#email').val();
           $.ajax({
           url:'validar-correo/{email}',
           type: "GET",
           success: function(response){
                 alert('Correcto');     
          },
           error: function(response){
         }
       });
       }
     </script>
```

este es mi controlador con el que trato de hacer la validación entro de la BD

```
public function validarUsuario ($email){
    //$correo = Registros::where($email, '=>', 'email');
    $correo = Registros::where('email', $email)->first();
              //if ($correo == 'email'){
                if ($correo){
                return response()->json(['error'=>'El correo ya existe'],422);
              }else{
                return response()->json(['success'=>'El correo no existe'],200);
              }

          }
```

esta es mi ruta que estoy utilizando

```
Route::get('validar-correo/{email}' , 'RegistroController@validarUsuario');
```

y este es mi input

```
<label>Correo electrónico</label>
                           <input type="email" name="email" id="email"   class="form-control" placeholder="ejem@ejem.com" 
                           onchange="validarCorreo()" required >
                           <div id="respuesta" class="col-lg-5"></div>
```

Muchas gracias Erick ***Duran*** por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme a solucionar mi problema.